# Converting column data to key-value pairs using shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file with 3 columns like below

```
1 104 Sam                        
1 0   Sam                 
2 18 George                     
2 26 George
```

I want this to converted to

```
1:[104,0,Sam]               
2:[18,26,George]
```

Can we acheive this using shell scripting or like `awk` command.

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Can you post your research efforts?

Comment: Can you also specify which shell you are using? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: In your example, first and last column define a unique key. So why do you want the name as last array element? There is no meaning for that. Or could you have many names per first column? If so, then example is not representative.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

save input in file `testdata`
then you can use something like this

`cat testdata | awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{line[i++]=$0}END{j=1; while (j<i) {print line[j],line[j+1]; j+=2}}' | awk '{print $1":" "[" $2 "," $5 "," $6 "]"}'`

Comment: If u don't mind could u please explain this as i m new to awk

Comment: This is hard printing of the example. Not a solution for any input file following the described schema.

Comment: This question and answer are a perfect example of GIGO.

Comment: Also how do we process if file is pipe seperated

Comment: Hey, chill guys thanasisp and Ed Morton. I am processing this data as part of cleansing and making them key,value pairs where 1st column is key and rest all are values, in actual it is a data with 20 columns and 30 records with pipe separator and i don't have any choice other than shell scripting as per demand. If u have got better solution i would be grateful.

Comment: "chill guys"? Did it seem like we're angry or something? Do you think thanasisp and I are the only people downvoting your question and this answer? Anyway - I would guess there's zero chance of anyone posting a better solution unless you post a better question. You posted a question that didn't conform to the guidelines (see [ask]) and is missing information, ignored requests for additional information, then accept the first, ludicrous answer you got and then told the people telling you that this is a bad answer to "chill", and then started turning it into a chameleon question. OK, good luck!